# How to configure OpenShift from Eclipse IDE?

Tags: eclipse, jboss, eclipse-plugin, openshift, openshift-cartridge

I want to deploy my web application using OpenShift. I have coded the same in Eclipse IDE. When I am trying to configure OpenShift from Eclipse by entering the Server URL and Token code, I get the following error:-

Unable to read endpoint https://api.us-west-2.online-starter.openshift.com/api

Following are the screenshots of the same:-

[image]

Thank you

Comment: Please retry by specifying port number `6443` (https://api.us-west-1.online-starter.openshift.com:6443/).

Comment: I tried doing the same, but it didn't work

Comment: Sorry Shashankk, it would appear that the Eclipse plugin is not compatible with OpenShift v4.